# grunt-coverjs is not working

Tags: gruntjs

I am using grunt version "0.4.1" and grunt-coverjs version "0.1.0". I am writing the task as below:
      `cover: {
        compile: {
            files: {
                'instrumented/testCoverage.js': ['src/file1.js'],
                'instrumented/testDir/*.js': ['src/file2.js', 'src/file3.js']
            }
        }
    }`

When i run the above task i am getting error as: Object # has no method 'expandFiles'.
I am not sure what is causing the error. 
Also, once the task is done, i think it is generated only the instrumented files, how can i generate the coverage report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means the task isn't compatible with Grunt `0.4.x` as `grunt.file.expandFiles` was deprecated. The author of that module can use `grunt.file.expand({filter: 'isFile'}, file.src)` instead. Although there is likely more updates that need to be done.

I'm sure the author would appreciate a pull request upgrading the module: https://github.com/jgrund/grunt-coverjs/blob/master/tasks/cover.js#L54

Here is the Grunt migration guide: http://gruntjs.com/upgrading-from-0.3-to-0.4